# Need to get the changing lat and lang from marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(7.5911419,79.8058212);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 10};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
  draggable:true,
 // animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
 });
marker.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
 console.log(myCenter.lat());
 });
}
```

This is the javascript code I use to map and the marker marker is draggable but when marker dragging the lattitude doesnot change I print the lat value in console and check it. And this is my html code.

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

can you please help me to slove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your event listener to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
   console.log(event.latLng.lat().toFixed(3), event.latLng.lng().toFixed(3));
});
```

Comment: @Dhananjana Not a problem!

Comment: Sorry I should say - if you want the full lat or lng value (including decimals) just remove `toFixed(3)`